# OpenGL - change light of a 3D sphere with popup menu

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut

I had updated after the suggestion in the comment sections. It should be better and working fine now. However, feel free to comment and discussion! I really wish to improve my programming in OpenGL!

---

I am new to OpenGL. I want to create a pop-up menu to change the lighting (ambient, diffuse, specular and position) of a sphere. However, there are some problems in showing the light. It works accordingly to click on the choice, e.g. ambient--> diffuse --> specular) but cannot work when (specular--> diffuse).

Here is the part of my code.

```
void display(void)
{
    GLfloat gray[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0 };
    GLfloat cyan[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat black[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat white[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, tdist);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)spinx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)spiny, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)spinz, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, gray);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, cyan);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, white);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POSITION, cyan);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 50);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    if (value == 2) {
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glPolygonOffset(polyfactor, polyunits);
        glCallList(list);
    }
    else if (value == 3) {
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
        glPolygonOffset(polyfactor, polyunits);
        glCallList(list);
    }
    else if (value == 4) {
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT2);
        glPolygonOffset(polyfactor, polyunits);
        glCallList(list);
    }
    else if (value == 5) {
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT3);
        glPolygonOffset(polyfactor, polyunits);
        glCallList(list);
    }

    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT2);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT3);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glCallList(list);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}
```

Thank you so much if anyone can help!!!

Comment: [`glMaterial`](http://docs.gl/gl2/glMaterial) does not switch from ambient to diffuse and specular. It sets the material color for ambien, diffuse and specular.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Do you know any function do this work? Can you please tell me or give me some hints ? Thanks so much if you can help!

Comment: For diffuse and specular light you have to se the light position and the normal vectors of the geometry. Anyway if the ambient material color is set once, then this state is kept.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Okay.Thanks so much for help! I will keep trying.

Comment: @Rabbid76  Thanks so much for the suggestion. I had made some improvements and hope you can help reading and give me some suggestion. It should be basically working fine